# Learn Python the Hard Way -- ex17.py under python-3 environment

Tags: python-3.x

I try to learn this book under python-3 environment but it pops out an error when I try to run it. Is there anywhere to fix this?

Once I deleted

```
print("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")
input()
```

The code ran perfectly. So I think it should be the syntax problem between python 2 and python 3

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print("Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file,to_file))

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print("The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata))

print("Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file))
print("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")
input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print("Alright, all done")

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

When I try to run it, it should stops at input() and wait me hit the return key to continue. But in reality, the code stopped and an error called

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex17.2.py", line 18, in <module>                                        g
    input("")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

popped out.

Comment: You won't get that kind of error unless you're using python2. `input()` is trying to "eval" the newline that it receives when you hit return.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct!! The error you are getting is due to python version change. This code works perfectly fine in python 3.x but fails in python version under 3.x.

Hope this helps.